# How to show the notify icon in taskbar for windows 7?

Tags: windows, visual-c++, notifyicon

I implement a notify icon for my application by call Shell_NotifyIcon.

In the default, the notify icon display in the notify icon area instead of task bar in windows 7.

If the user want to show the notify icon in the task bar, he/she need to open the Notification Area Icons control panel item, find the application and set "Show icon and notifications" for the application.

I think it will be difficult to the user with poor windows knowledge. I want to implement this function that show the notify icon in the task bar in my VC++ code or installer. Is it possible? If yes, what should I do?

Appreciate.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

No, this is not possible.

Windows 7 introduces a feature where notification icons can be hidden. It is an attempt to reduce the noise created by decades of developers dumping notification icons in the taskbar for no good reason.

In order for that feature to work effectively, there can't be a loophole for applications to get around it, because everyone thinks their application is the most important and the most deserving of prime real estate. Eventually, nothing is sacred anymore.

Raymond Chen has [blogged about this very request](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2010/12/15/10105142.aspx), and provides [some additional background info](http://blogs.msdn.com/b/oldnewthing/archive/2006/11/01/922449.aspx).

You just create the notification icon and provide the user with instructions *in the documentation* on how to show it permanently, if they so desire.

Answer (score 0):

Why not just pin your application to the task bar? They can just click it and it will launch the application?

Comment: Applications can't pin themselves to the taskbar, either. For the same reasons.